# How to split gz csv file by it's data field efficiently

Tags: python-2.7, hive, etl

I have a very large gzipped csv file. I would like to split it into two gz files based on the string pattern in a particular column. I know it is possible to loop through the content and create two files, but is there a better way to do it in python in terms of efficiency?

In addition, the original file has one line header. I would like to either have the headers in each of the two result files, or remove headers altogether.

Comment: you want to split the files to 2 gz files using python?

Comment: yes, split 1 large gz file to 2 based on column value.

Comment: you could just open your input file using gzopen and create 2 gzopen output files, and work with csv like normal files. That would work.